# ruby array behave strange in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

let say I have 2 arrays 
@arr1 = [10,20,30,40]
@arr2 = [30,40,50,60]

In rails controller I am trying to find both diffs and according it add or remove records.
If I do in console simple `@diff1 = (@arr1 - @arr2)` I get correct result [10,20]

if I do in rails controller the same, I get whole @arr1 instead of @diff1 so I tried simple `puts (@arr1 - @arr2)` but with wrong result
here is the sample code:

```
@associates = params[:associate_to]
      @coordinators = @guild.coordinators.pluck(:coordinator_id)

      @to_add = (@associates-@coordinators)

      @to_remove = (@coordinators-@associates)
      puts "first array"
      puts @associates
      puts "----"
      puts "second array"
      puts @coordinators
      puts "-----"

      puts "calculation"      
      puts (@associates-@coordinators)
      puts "result"
      puts @to_add
```

and here is result from rails server

[image]

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try putting spaces around the minus sign? might be being interpreted oddly (ie as unary negative for some reason). `@to_add = (@associates - @coordinators)`

Comment: Also... when you use `puts` please use `inspect` - it can make all the difference. So: `puts @associates.inspect` and `puts (@associates - @coordinators).inspect` -> sometime's Rails implicit `to_s` can cause two different things to *appear* to be the same when they're really not. So do this now for all your `puts`s and then show us the new results.

Comment: Also, since `@associates` comes from `params` and `@coordinators` comes from database records; It's very likely `@associates` is an array of strings while `@coordinators` is an array of integers. Maybe try `@associates = params[:associate_to].map(&:to_i)`

Comment: I bet on the good ol' String vs Integer comparison

Comment: Yup - that's why `inspect` is an excellent thing when using `puts`... it will instantly show you the difference...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably because one array contains integers and the other contains strings. Try converting elements of one of the arrays to string or int.

```
arr.map(&:to_i)
# or
arr.map(&:to_s)
```